# Anyway to download wwdc videos without itunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, wwdc

iTunes download speed sucks and it is also unstable. I end up waste much eletricity with many unfinished files. Is there a way to use any download tools to fetch the videos?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. (StackOverflow thinks that the answer should be longer. In this case, though, "no" is the correct answer.)

**Update:** As a registered Apple developer, you can view the WWDC 2011 videos in Safari [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/index.php).